# How to remove rows based on a column value where some row's column value are subset of another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a `dataframe` df as:-

```
index company  url                          address 
 0     A .    www.abc.contact.com         16D Bayberry Rd, New Bedford, MA, 02740, USA
 1     A .    www.abc.contact.com .       MA, USA
 2     A .    www.abc.about.com .         USA
 3     B .    www.pqr.com .               New Bedford, MA, USA
 4     B.     www.pqr.com/about .         MA, USA
```

I want to remove all the rows from the `dataframe` where `address` is subset of another address and company is same. Eg, I want these two rows out of above 5 rows.

```
index  company  url                          address 
 0     A .    www.abc.contact.com         16D Bayberry Rd, New Bedford, MA, 02740, USA
 3     B .    www.pqr.com .               New Bedford, MA, USA
```

Comment: What defines `subset`? Because the string `'MA, USA'` is not a substring of anything within `company='A'`. The first row does contain both of those words separately, but then do you expect each part of address to be split by commas and to check those separately?

Comment: @ALollz by `subset`, I mean after removing punctuations, we should get the string address which contains all other addresses listed (like string subset match).

Comment: @Harry_pb This is not a trivial case. And running it would probably be time consuming, as you have to remove punctuations, then split a string, then check if all of its substrings are present elsewhere in `address` column within a company. Repeat it for every row. It's crazy! Could you simplify it somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is not an optimal solution, but it does the work on this small dataframe:

**EDIT** added checking for company names, assuming that we removed punctuation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"company": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   "address": ['16D Bayberry Rd, New Bedford, MA, 02740, USA',
                               'MA, USA',
                               'USA',
                               'New Bedford, MA, USA',
                               'MA, USA']})
# Splitting addresses by column and making sets from every address to use "issubset" later
addresses = list(df['address'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(', '))).values)
companies = list(df['company'].values)

rows_to_drop = []  # Storing row indexes to drop here
# Iterating by every address
for i, (address, company) in enumerate(zip(addresses, companies)):
    # Iteraing by the remaining addresses
    rem_addr = addresses[:i] + addresses[(i + 1):]
    rem_comp = companies[:i] + companies[(i + 1):]

    for other_addr, other_comp in zip(rem_addr, rem_comp):
        # If address is a subset of another address, add it to drop
        if address.issubset(other_addr) and company == other_comp:
            rows_to_drop.append(i)
            break

df = df.drop(rows_to_drop)
print(df)

company address
0   A   16D Bayberry Rd, New Bedford, MA, 02740, USA
3   B   New Bedford, MA, USA
```

Comment: This solution doesn't take companies into consideration. That's why you successfully discarded "MA, USA" in company A, although it is not a substring of any address in it (literally). A more sophisticated search is necessary in this case (e.g. `split` based).

Comment: @teoretic Thanks for your response, the problem I am facing here is not just to get the unique list of address but also to manage company and url aligned with the address, because I have very large dataset with address repeating for other companies as well, i.e many companies have same office locations.

Comment: @Harry_pb I edited my answer, hope that this will help!

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem after some modifications on large scale. Cheers !!